# How do I display my paperclip image on a profile page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, devise, paperclip, image-uploading

I am very new to rails and am attempting to get some practice by building a profile page. I have implemented devise and once a user has signed in they can click on a link that displays a profile with information about them. Right now it is just displaying their name, date of birth, and gender. I would like for it to also display an image of them. So I have bundled the paperclip gem and read through some tutorials to try and get it configured. I have gotten the code in place, so that a user can click on 'choose file' and select an image. However when I click 'update' it provides me with an error. I'd like for the image to display on the same show page of their profile.

**profiles_controller.rb**

```
  class Users::ProfilesController < ApplicationController
    def edit
      @profile = Profile.create(params[:photo])
    end

    def create
    end

    private 

    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:photo)
    end
  end
```

**profiles/edit.html.erb**

```
<h2>Edit Account Profile </h2>


<%= form_for(@profile, url: profiles_edit_path(@profile), html: { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>


  <li>
    <%= f.label :photo, "Photo" %>
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  </li>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

**registrations/show.html.erb**

```
<%= image_tag @profile.photo.url %>
<br>
<%= @user.email %>
<br>
<%= @user.first_name %>
<%= @user.last_name %>
<br>
<%= @user.date_of_birth %>
<br>
<%= @user.is_female %>
```

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def show 
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end


  private

    def sign_up_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :is_female, :date_of_birth,  :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    def account_update_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :is_female, :date_of_birth, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
    end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'users/registrations', :profiles => 'users/profiles' }

  devise_scope :user do
    get 'profiles/edit' => 'users/profiles#edit'
    post 'profiles/edit' => 'users/profiles#edit'
    get 'users/:id' => 'users/registrations#show', as: :user 
  end


  root to: "home#index"


end
```

Error after clicking update:

Routing Error
No route matches [PATCH] "/profiles/edit.21"

I appreciate any assistance, and please let me know if any further information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this route to devise_scope to pass that error

```
patch 'profiles/edit' => 'users/profiles#edit'
```

btw, in ProfilesController

- creating new Profile should be in `create` action
- in `edit` action, you should load existed profile and render edit view

**Update:**

- form in `edit` view will submit data to action `update`, we need get profile again and update data for it

your routes is not correct, when edit a profile, we should submit to a url look like `users/profiles/4/update`

you can declare routes as below

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'users/registrations' }
 namespace :users do
   resources :profiles
 end
```

In `update` action, you retrieve that profile `p = Profile.find(params[:id])` and update it `p.photo = params[:photo]; p.save` or anything you want

Comment: Thanks allot for the help! As you suggested I added patch 'profiles/edit' => 'users/profiles#edit' to the routes file. I also moved the creating of a new profile into the create action. Now I am receiving ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Users::ProfilesController#edit

Comment: It sounds like in the edit action of the profiles controller, I have to put some logic to load the existing user's profile page...

Comment: @DamonClark i just update the answer, hope it can help you

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
patch 'profiles/:id' => 'users/profiles#update'
```

and form helper should like this:

```
<%= form_for(@profile, html: { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
```

Hope it is helpful for you!!

Comment: I am getting Couldn't find Profile with 'id'=     I am assuming that I don't have any Profile created... I feel like I have to add some logic to connect the User table with the Profile table.